# Visual Studio Platform toolset and Runtime Library

Tags: c++, visual-studio

After browsing here and there, i have come to following conclusion

1. Visual Studio Platform Toolset - Compiler, Linker, Assembler etc which changes with each version of Visual Studio (mostly).

> Note : If your project is built with previous version of Platform
>   toolset then it may not work as such with newer version of platform
>   toolset as they may be incompatible.

2. Runtime Library - A library which assists in running the code(program) you write by acting as an intermediary between Program and Operating system. It has various options like /Mt /Mtd /MD /MDd which stand for multithreaded static, multithreaded staticdebug, multithreaded dynamic, multithreaded dynamic debug respcetiviely

> Note: All modules of your code must be using same Runtime to be
>   compatible i.e one module built with /Mt should be used with
>   application too using Runtime library as /Mt else there may be issues.

Am i right in my summary above? Or still i am not clear about this? Can anyone provide their inputs

I have googled, played tutorials and tried to consolidate all the information above. Not sure did i understand it or still having some bits and pieces missing.

`SHARED ABOVE`

Comment: I reformatted your question as I struggled to understand what was your words and question, and what appears to be quotes from external source. If I'm wrong then apologies and please rollback the edit.

Comment: Thanks acraig5075. I just wrote all by myself but i agree its looks better after your formatting.

Comment: They make a *lot* of effort to ensure that a newer version of the toolset does not break old programs, so you need to dismiss 1.  The /MT option is not suitable for programs that use multiple modules, /MD ensures they share the same C and C++ runtime libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The platform toolset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-modify-the-target-framework-and-platform-toolset?view=vs-2019#platform-toolset) consists of the C++ compiler (cl.exe) and linker (link.exe), along with the C/C++ standard libraries. Since Visual Studio 2015, the major version of the toolset has remained at 14, which means that projects compiled with Visual Studio 2019 or Visual Studio 2017 are ABI-backwards-compatible with projects compiled with Visual Studio 2015.

The Microsoft run-time library provides routines for programming for the Microsoft Windows operating system. These routines automate many common programming tasks that are not provided by the C and C++ languages.[The C Run-time Library (CRT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=vs-2019#c-run-time-libraries-crt) is the part of the C++ Standard Library that incorporates the ISO C99 standard library. The Visual C++ libraries that implement the CRT support native code development, and both mixed native and managed code. All versions of the CRT support multi-threaded development. Most of the libraries support both static linking, to link the library directly into your code, or dynamic linking to let your code use common DLL files.

Comment: Hi
I think again your answer mixed me up. You mentioned that the platform toolset contains C/C++ standard libraries. Did you mean "STL libraries"? Then you mentioned that the C Run-time Library (CRT) is the part of the C++ Standard Library that incorporates the ISO C99 standard library. Does this mean that CRT is part of  Platform toolset as you earlier mentioned that C/C++ standard libraries are part of platform toolset?
I am getting confused here ... Can you explain with a simple language by mentioning how STL library are different than C Runtime library?

Comment: The C Run-time Library (CRT) is the part of the C++ Standard Library that incorporates the ISO C99 standard library.

C++ standard library is a term to define the standard library that a minimum conforming compiler/toolset should have. C++ runtime library is the library shipped with the toolset to provide standard library functionality, and probably some internal stuff the compiler might need.

Comment: To put things together, Is that correct to say that when a C++ programmer writes code he uses the functions from C++ Standard Library (or from C++ STL) and in order to run the compiled and linked C++ code, Visual studio needs the C Runtime Library. The /Mt /Md options enable the programmer to choose whether to link the C Runtime Library either Statically or Dynamically. 
To add cross platforms, we can say that Windows provides C++ Standard Library and C Runtime library as part of Windows SDK. However on Linux, The C Runtime is provided by libC which we can link statically or dynamically.

Comment: Continuation ........ Does the C++ standard library on linux differs from the C++ standard library on Windows OR are they basically the same thing?

Comment: The C++ standard library on Linux is basically the same as the C++ standard library on Windows, but there are differences in implementation. I suggest you can refer to this [link](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/c-c-standard-library).